# Townsend's Infinitesimal Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I'm currently reading John Townsend's Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics and the infinitesimal operators have me a bit puzzled:

$$\hat R(d\phi \boldsymbol{k})=1-{i \over \hbar}\hat J_zd\phi$$
$$\hat U(dt)=1-{i \over \hbar}\hat Hdt$$
$$\hat T(dx)=1-{i \over \hbar}\hat p_xdx$$

These are used to define their respective operators as an infinite number of infinitesimal operations.

I'm left wondering where these definitions come from and how to make sense of them without being circular. I feel like a truncated series expansion is involved, but an expansion of what?

Appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps Lie group theory would give be a good place to look for inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation without exponentials. For the translation operator, for example, we want (by definition of what the translation operator should do)
\begin{align}
\left<x\right|T(\epsilon) \left| \psi \right> 
&= \left<x + \epsilon\right|\left. \psi \right>\\ 
&= \psi(x + \epsilon)\\ 
&\approx \psi(x) + \epsilon \,\psi'(x)\\
&= (1 + \epsilon \partial_x)\psi(x)\\
&= \left<x\right| \left(1 - \frac{i \epsilon}{\hbar} \hat{p}_x \right)\left|\psi\right>
\end{align}
So we identify
\begin{align}
T(\epsilon) = 1 - \frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\hat{p}_x
\end{align}
and similarly for the others.

Comment: The “weakness”of this argument is it depends on existence of derivative; the “classic” counter example is in Griffiths: $\psi(x)\sim e^{-\lambda \vert x\vert}$

Answer (score 1):

The exponential of an operator is defined by its series so
\begin{align}
e^A= 1+ A +\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\frac{1}{3!}A^3
\end{align}
so we have, respectively 
\begin{align}
R_z(\phi)&=e^{-i \hat J_z \phi/\hbar}&\approx 1-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat J_z \phi +\ldots \, ,\tag{1}\\
U(t)&=e^{-i \hat H t/\hbar}&\approx  1-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat H t+\ldots \, ,\\
T(x)&=e^{-i \hat p x/\hbar}&\approx 1-\frac{i}{\hbar} x \hat p +\ldots\, .
\end{align}

Townsend truncates the series by considering - for $R_z$- a small angle $d\phi$ rather than a finite angle $\phi$ as in (1), and discards any term of degree 2 or higher in $d\phi$.  A similar procedure is done for the other cases.

Thus, the generator of infinitesimal rotations $J_z$ appears as a derivative of $R_z(\phi)$ w/r to the variable $\phi$, with the derivative evaluated at $\phi=0$, i.e. 
$$
J_z=i\hbar \frac{d}{d\phi}R_z(\phi)\Bigl\vert_{\phi=0}\, ,
$$
or alternatively (up to $i\hbar$) as the operator which multiplies the linear term in the infinitesimal transformation $R_z(d\phi)$.  This actually *defines* the generator.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! 

I had concerns about being circular because Townsend begins with $$\hat R(d\phi \boldsymbol{k})=1-{i \over \hbar}\hat J_zd\phi$$ and uses that to derive $$R_z(\phi)=e^{-i \hat J_z \phi/\hbar}$$ which appears to be the opposite of what you've done. Is there a way to get the infinitesimal operator without assuming the exponential definition?

Comment: You can start with the matrix representation of a rotation and take the derivative to get the generators for rotations about each axes, look at the commutations and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

For the translation operator, according to Sakurai (2nd ed, pp. 42-46), there are four conditions we want the infinitesimal translations to accomplish:

1) If $|\alpha\rangle$ is normalized, then so is the translated ket $\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x})|\alpha\rangle$

2) $\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x'})\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x''})=\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x'}+d\mathbf{x''})$

3) $\hat{T}(-d\mathbf{x})=\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x})^{-1}$

4) $\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x})\rightarrow 1$ as $d\mathbf{x}\rightarrow 0$

All of these conditions are satisfied if we take $\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x'})=1-i\mathbf{K} \cdot d\mathbf{x'}$, where $\mathbf{K}$ components are hermitian operators and $d\mathbf{x'}$ components are real numbers.

Then, we borrow from classical mechanics the fact that linear momentum is the generator of translations. Sakurai goes explicit on this, remarking that an infinitesimal translation can be regarded as the following canonical transformation (in classical mechanics):

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}_{\text{new}} = \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x} + d\mathbf{x} \qquad 
\mathbf{p}_{\text{new}} = \mathbf{P} = \mathbf{p}
\end{equation}
And this is obtainable from the generating function $F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{P}) = \mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{P}+\mathbf{p}\cdot d\mathbf{x}$

Now, it is done the following comparison:

\begin{align}
\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x'}) &=1-i\mathbf{K} \cdot d\mathbf{x'} \quad (\text{Quantum Mechanics})\\
F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{P}) &= \mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{P}+\mathbf{p}\cdot d\mathbf{x}\quad (\text{Classical Mechanics})
\end{align}

Recalling that $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{P}$ is the generating function for the identity canonical transformation ($\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{p}$), Sakurai allow us to speculate that $\mathbf{K}$ is somehow related to $\mathbf{p}$, given the striking similarity of the two equations above.

At this point I admit I don't understand why there is a relation between the two concepts: on the one hand, the infinitesimal translation operator $\hat{T}(d\mathbf{x})$ from quantum mechanics, and on the other hand, the generating function $F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{P})$ from classical mechanics. I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify this point in the comments.

But, moving on, for the units to match up, it is set:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{K} = \frac{\mathbf{p}}{\text{universal constant with the dimension of action}} = \frac{\mathbf{p}}{\hbar}
\end{equation}

The actual numerical value of the constant would not be important as we could change the basic units so that its value would be unity. I recommend reading this section on Sakurai ($\S$ *1.6 Position, momentum and translation*), from where I based my answer.